# Getting Error : Invalid Column NoteId

Tags: acumatica

I have requirement to add  Image for each serial number.

I have extended the INItemLotSerial and added ImageUrl & NoteID field

```
[PXTable(typeof(INItemLotSerial.inventoryID),
 typeof(INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr),
 IsOptional = true)]
public class InfoINItemLotSerialExtNV : PXCacheExtension<INItemLotSerial>
```

The DAC Having the following code for NoteID

```
#region NoteID
    public abstract class noteID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Guid? _NoteID;
    [PXNote]
    public virtual Guid? NoteID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._NoteID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._NoteID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

while saving the Purchase receipt document after entering serial numbers, I am getting error Invalid Column : NoteID

`

Comment: Did you make sure your database table has that field? and that the site either published the change or if you updated the field outside of the site, recycle the site so it sees the change. I am not sure how well PXNote would work as an extension.

Comment: Yes.. it is part of dll and published

Comment: In your example what's the purpose of the PXTable attribute? I don't think this is helpful here. Invalid column error message usually means the column is not in the database table. Use a SQL management utility like SQL Management Studio to manually confirm a column named 'NoteID' is present.

Comment: It looks like PXNote is not working on Extension Table. I have added the Column on INItemLotSerial and removed from extension table. This solved the Invalid column issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, PXNoteAttribute do not support extension tables, so your only option is use a regular extension for the INItemLotSerial DAC over an extension table.